# Would a 20 amp 240 volt panel from the main panel be enough for a laundry room?

Tags: electrical

Would a 20 amp 240 volt panel be good enough for three circuits, of total 40 amps 120 volts in a laundry room?

Answer (score 3):

If the laundry room does *not* have an electric clothes dryer, then yes, 20 amps at 240 volts should be adequate.  That could be arranged as a pair of 20 amp 120 volt circuits:  one for the clothes washer and an iron, and the other for the motor of a gas or propane clothes dryer.

However, if an electric clothes dryer is needed, that alone should be a 30 amp (or larger) 240 volt dedicated circuit.  Another 120 volt circuit at 20 amps for the clothes washer and iron, etc.  The total is at least 50 amps.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not. While a 20A 240V can supply 2 20A 120V circuits, a third circuit will be on one phase or the other, so you'd very likely end up overloading the supply on one phase (I'm also not sure how you are going to end up with 40A divided across 3 circuits with typical circuit breaker sizes.) I don't believe there are many options where "1 20 amp and 2 10 amp" breakers can actually be used, given that circuits with outlets are 15 amp minimum supply.

In the normal case of 15 Amp breakers as a minimum, 3 circuits will be 15A on one phase and 30A on the other.

So while you can supply two circuits at 20A 120V for a total of 40A, three is almost certainly going to require a larger feed to the sub-panel.

Comment: you are right. Would a 20amp at 120v be used with receptacles and the clothes washer and a separate 15amp at 120v for lights and exhaust fan? Or 20amp 120v for lights and receptacles, and lights and fan,  and 15amp for clothes washer?

Comment: you are right. Would a 20amp at 120v be used with receptacles and the clothes washer and a separate 15amp at 120v for lights and exhaust fan? Or 20amp 120v for lights and receptacles, and lights and fan,  and 15amp for clothes washer?  The washer only use 10amp, said by the manufacturer.

Comment: i am sorry. But if i can put a 30amp 240v from the main panel, would that be much safe for the laundry room sub penal to provide electric power to its use.  please help

Comment: The laundry room has only two lights, one fan, two receptacles and a washer plus a gas dryer.